# View h264 from rtmpsrc via gstreamer

Tags: h.264, gstreamer, rtmp, flash-media-server

I want to play flash media server stream via gstreamer. My video is published from camera to FMS with h264 encoding (720x480 Main,3.0).

My command for ubuntu is:

> gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc
>   location="rtmp://192.168.1.153:1935/appname/mp4:cameraFeed44.mp4
>   live=1" ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue ! videoconvert !
>   queue ! xvimagesink

For resolution 720x480 it throws:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2812): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/    GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

However it works fine for low resolution, like: 320x240. But I need even more than FullHD.

Thanks,

Stan

Comment: Try to put `queue` before `decodebin`

Comment: Just tried. Doesn't help.